# Serious MongoDB Question

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I've been running a nodejs application against mongo db for a couple of weeks. Today, I wrote a new script to extract some data and write to a CSV. As I ran this, I suddenly started getting connection errors. I found I was unable to connect to Mongo either through my application or at the console.

In the console, I ran mongod -- repair and then for my database db.repairDatabase().

I've now lost all my data. I can't see any way to recover it. Has anyone else experienced this and if so, do you have any idea what I can do?

Comment: Some log file entries corresponding to the time of crash and repair would be useful. That's the only thing that can tell us what caused the crash in the first place and what it did during the repair. Crystal ball gazing is really difficult. :)

Comment: FYI your logs are stored in the place where you specified with --logpath on the command line.

Comment: @Scheiner please post your mongod log file showing the error messages